# Why such way of object creation has been used in Java Script?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Could some one please explain to me, why in d3-tip library (https://github.com/Caged/d3-tip), the object constructor looks like this:

```
d3.tip = function() {
var direction = d3_tip_direction,
      offset    = d3_tip_offset,
      html      = d3_tip_html,
      node      = initNode(),
      svg       = null,
      point     = null,
      target    = null

  function tip(vis) {
    svg = getSVGNode(vis)
    point = svg.createSVGPoint()
    document.body.appendChild(node)
  }

  tip.show = function() {
     // some function
  }

  //...

  return tip
}
```

To explain my confusion, I'm trying to replicate this library with different behaviour and can't make a decision, should I left this pattern as it is or change it into more standard creation function.

Comment: Youve cut out pretty much everything that would make that pattern explainable.

Comment: They do lots of different things there, all of which are common JS patterns. I've no idea which one you are wondering about, why you would expect something else or what that something else might be.

Comment: Here is explanation from the creator of d3.js: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function returns the tip function/object. at the bottom of the function it `return tip`; which is the new tip function.

by doing this the variables  `var direction = d3_tip_direction // etc` are protected and are not accessible outside of the functions scope.

To understand further, you should look into design patterns, there is an [excellent resource here](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/)

Comment: Protected? I didn't know one could have protected members in java script, thanks

Comment: protected in the sense that they are out of scope for the application using the object.

Comment: Yes, I just realised that. Thanks for the book btw